# Pyyaml file installation on Python 3.9.2 (64bit)

Tags: python, pyyaml

i am trying to install pyYAML on python 3.9.2 (64bit), but not able to find the right link from where i can download the same. please help...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and revise your question

Answer (score 1):

Once you have Python installed, you generally install library packages using a command-line tool called `pip`, which takes care of downloading the package for you.

As [documented](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), this should work:

```
pip install pyyaml
```